# ASP.NET MVC 5 vNext make web request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am trying to do a web request from my ASP.NET MVC 6 application to another resource. I tried to use HttpClient and WebClient but all of these classes are unavailable for me.

I tried adding this:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { },
    "aspnet50": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "aspnetcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0-beta-*"
      }
    }
  }
```

But didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add `System.Net.Http` to my `project.json` file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0"
  }
```